# ObjectId fails to be posted

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create a new item for my collection "guess", but one element (ask_id, of 'ObjectId' datatype) is never recognized, leading to a failed validation.

Here is the model:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose'; 
const {Schema, model} = mongoose; 

const guessSchema = new Schema ({
   body:{type:String, required:true},
   source:{type:String, required:true},
   ask_id:{type:Schema.Types.ObjectId, required:true, ref:"ask"},
   comment:{type:String, required:false},
})
```

here is the post request:

```
{
"body": "hello ",
"comment": "ffff",
"source": "https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform",
"ask_id": "608c13d323b3455db014ca6d"
}
```

here is what error message I receive:

```
"error": "guess validation failed: ask_id: Path `ask_id` is required."
```

Could someone please help me figure out what I did wrong here? The path seems to match :(

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it... that was so stupid. In my createGuess function, I had forgotten to put ask_id è_é

How it was written:

```
const {body, source, comment} = req.body
  const newGuess = await guess.create({
     body,
     source,
     comment
  })
```

How it should have been written:

```
  const {body, source, comment, ask_id} = req.body
  const newGuess = await guess.create({
     body,
     source,
     comment,
     ask_id
  })
```

I'm leaving this here in case someone does the same silly oversight.

Answer (score 1):

Try casting the "ask_id" string value to the Mongoose ObjectId.

```
let ask_id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId('608c13d323b3455db014ca6d');
```

In the POST body you mentioned, replace the string `ask_id` with this new `ask_id` variable.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately, it's still not working. Same error message.

Comment: ask_id is posted as follow: ask_id: Object { _bsontype: "ObjectID", id: Uint8Array(12) }

Comment: can you show the validation code, if you are doing custom validation?

Comment: found it... that was so stupid. In my createGuess function, I had forgotten to put ask_id è_é

Comment: thanks so much for you time, and my apologies for the disturbance :/